# Phonegap "OFFLINE" application + ARCGIS for javascript

Tags: cordova, dojo, offline, arcgis

The condition is like this.The app will be connected to the vpn and used.
The app runs offline or in VPN
I want to show the map with pins[annotation & callouts]
ESRI provides the library in DOJO[ARCGIS for JS]

How I am supposed to run the application in VPN or Offline where DOJO CDN is NOT getting downloaded and no function call is getting performed.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ArcGIS API for JavaScript includes the Dojo libraries. You can download the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to host it locally; then you'll have Dojo locally as well. See [the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_accessapi.html) for details (look at the bottom of the page for info on downloading the API).